# fetch data from firebase to list use model in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

first my data in firebase like this
[image]

I try to get data from firebase realtime to List in Flutter use model. but show some error.
i have products in firebase ,i try to get products to list use model
when run my app display some error

class **Product.dart**

```
 class Product {
  final int id;
  final String title, description;
  final List<String> images;
  final List<Color> colors;
   final double rating, price;
  final bool isFavourite, isPopular;

  Product({
     this.id,
     this.images,
     this.colors,
    this.rating = 0.0,
    this.isFavourite = false,
    this.isPopular = false,
     this.title,
     this.price,
     this.description,
  });
  

}

List<Product> demoProducts=[];
```

in page popular data
itemBuilder: (context, index) => ProductCard(
product: demoProducts[index],

and in page productcard
Text(
"${product.price}",

```
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(18),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: What are the two `$$` for? Have you tried just using one like: `"${product.price}"`?

Comment: @WillHlas I know but dont know how can get data from firebase to List<Product> demoProducts=[];

Comment: @EmadAljumaily Please include how you get data from firebase to List<Product> then it's easy for us to inspect the problem.

Comment: @WillHlas In fact, I searched a lot and couldn't find what I wanted
You can watch this and you will know exactly what I want  https://github.com/emadaljumaily/comerce/